# Pass perl file arguments to LWP HTTP request

Tags: perl, perl-module, lwp, lwp-useragent

Here is my issue with handling argument Perl. I need to pass Perl argument argument to a http request (Webservice) whatever Argument given to the perl file.

```
perl wsgrep.pl  -name=john -weight -employeeid -cardtype=physical
```

In the wsgrep.pl file, i need to pass the above arguments to http post params.

like below,

```
http://example.com/query?name=john&weight&employeeid&cardtype=physical.
```

I am using LWP Package for this url to get response.

Is there any good approach to do this?

Updated:
Inside the wsgrep.pl

```
my ( %args, %config );

my $ws_url =
"http://example.com/query";

my $browser  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
# Currently i have hard-coded the post param arguments. But it should dynamic based on the file arguments. 
my $response = $browser->post(
    $ws_url,
    [
        'name' => 'john',
        'cardtype'  => 'physical'
    ],
);

if ( $response->is_success ) {
    print $response->content;
}
else {
    print "Failed to query webservice";
    return 0;
}
```

I need to construct post parameter part from the given arguments.

```
[
            'name' => 'john',
            'cardtype'  => 'physical'
        ],
```

Comment: What is this `wsgrep.pl` that you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, to url-encode params, I'd use the following:

```
use URI;

my $url = URI->new('http://example.com/query');
$url->query_form(%params);

say $url;
```

Your needs are more elaborate.

```
use URI         qw( );
use URI::Escape qw( uri_escape );

my $url = URI->new('http://example.com/query');

my @escaped_args;
for (@ARGV) {
   my ($arg) = /^-(.*)/s
      or die("usage");

   push @escaped_args,
      join '=',
         map uri_escape($_),
            split /=/, $arg, 2;
}

$url->query(@escaped_args ? join('&', @escaped_args) : undef);

say $url;
```

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm. Thank you Sir!